# Where to store SQLITE db file in electron production mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron, electron-builder

I'm building portable node js server using electron. I'm using SQLITE database for storing data.

In development mode I put database file `test.db` in directory where is my `Main.js` file and everything is running perfectly.

When I deploy my app `electron-builder --mac` and run it, it cannot access to database file. (File not found)

So my question is where should I store my `test.db` file so it's working both in development and production mode?

Is it possible to embed db file somewhere while creating application for win/mac/linux so end user doesn't need to take care where is db file located?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

you can store it into application data,
`const dbPath = path.join(app.getPath("userData"), "sample.db")`

Check out docs here,
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname